# Does order matter in extended regular expressions with []?

Tags: regex, grep

I'm trying to understand the `[]` syntax with extended regular expressions in grep.

The following two patterns are equivalent:

```
$ echo "foo_bar" | grep -E "[a-z_]+$"     
foo_bar
$ echo "foo_bar" | grep -E "[_a-z]+$" 
foo_bar
```

However, these two are not:

```
$ echo "foobar[]" | grep -E "[a-z_\[\]]+$" 
foobar[]
$ echo "foobar[]" | grep -E "[a-z\[\]_]+$"
```

Why is this? Is this documented anywhere? I couldn't see anything in `man grep` about this.

Comment: Nope, both are identical on my regex platform. No hidden characters in either regex nor target. Both work fine. And, while there is a precedence in  classes, left to right, the target is the gorilla that controls it.

Comment: @sln that was my thought but I don't have access to a bash console to test it in. OP: does switching to single quotes fix the problem?

Comment: @AdamSmith https://rextester.com/l/bash_online_compiler might be useful.

Comment: @Wilfred Hughes Is your issue resolved?

Answer (score 2):

You should be careful when using double quotes `"` and backslashes `\` since BASH handles the backslashes first. This changes your regular expression to `[a-z_[]]+$`. However there still is a fine point and for the remainder of this question I assume that you had used single quotes.

In the first case you have the character group `[a-z_\[\]`, which matches characters `a-z`, `_`, `\`, `[`. The final `\]` does not list `]` as another character of the character group but rather is another `\` and a the closing bracket of the character class. Notice how:

```
$ echo "foobar[]" | grep -E '[a-z\[\]+\]+$'
foobar[]
$ echo '\' | grep -E '[\]$'
\
```

If you want to add `]` you have to list it first, that is `[]]` matches a single `]`.

```
$ echo "]" | grep -E '[]]$'
]
```

For a reference see `man grep`:

> To include a literal ] place it first in the list. Similarly, to include a literal ^ place it anywhere but first. Finally, to include a literal - place it last.

as well as https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html

> In most regex flavors, the only special characters or metacharacters inside a character class are the closing bracket ], the backslash \, the caret ^, and the hyphen -. The usual metacharacters are normal characters inside a character class, and do not need to be escaped by a backslash. To search for a star or plus, use [+*]. Your regex will work fine if you escape the regular metacharacters inside a character class, but doing so significantly reduces readability.

Even more test cases to examine `[\s]` (which is the same as `[s\]` and different from `[[:space:]]`):

```
$ echo 'a ' | grep -E 'a[\s]$'
$ echo 's' | grep -E '[\s]$'
s
$ echo '\' | grep -E '[\s]$'
\
$ echo 'a ' | grep -E 'a[[:space:]]$'
a
```

So the takeaway is: Order does not matter when listing characters of a character class, except when it does.

Comment: so this is the funny interpretation of -E regexes by grep. Is it true for every grep? I mean, it's true on my Mac, but BSD is quite stubborn sometimes...

Comment: On that rextester site, I ran a simple grep using `'^[\]+$'` and it matched \\\\\\\ which tells me that indeed, that grep only recognizes particular escapes, like `\s`, etc. Which you can come to the conclusion that `[a-z\[\]` is one chunk, and `_]+$` the other. Since there was no `_]` at the end, it did not match anything. Kind of misleading, if you remove the escapes, you get the same result (sans the escape). Either way, it must be a very old type of piece of code. Should be replaced with something else. https://rextester.com/RYTNJ61355

Comment: @AdamSmith `-E` is not PCRE, it's "extended regexp". To get PCRE you have to use `grep -P`, which I think is only available in GNU grep.

Comment: @Barmar AH-HA! There lies my confusion. Now it's all clear to me -- thanks :)

Comment: The other confusing part of -E regexes is that, while a `[` without the corresponding `]` is an error, a lonely `]` is matched literally. If it weren't, the regexes in the question would have caused an error (which would have been a better choice, IMHO)